# How to make a live stream redirector?

Tags: c#, wpf, video, redirect, feed

So I have a local URL like http://localhost:port/ with live video stream in it. I need to send it over TCP to http://any_address:AnyPort/ how to do such thing in WPF, C#? CODE WANTED!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpWebRequest.

Create one to get the stream then take the response and craft your response on the 222 server to mirror the response received from localhost changing necessary headers.

Comment: It is not a snippet of code, I told you how, I doubt anyone is willing to write it all for you.